# TouchID doesn't always work

Tags: macos, password, touch-id

Touch ID works fine, but not always.

I can understand that after a reboot or a logout / login, a password is required, but sometimes a password is required only an hour after closing the laptop lid and reopening it.

Some services don't accept a Touch ID such as installing applications. The installer which used macOS services, still does not accept Touch ID.

I am not talking about passwords in 3rd party apps, in that case app developers are responsible. This occurs both on a Macbook Pro 2018 13" (Intel) and Macbook Pro 2021 14" M1.

Under which circumstances is Touch ID enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Apple documents when it requires a password here : https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-touch-id-mchl16fbf90a/mac

> when you start your Mac

and

> must re-enter their password every 48 hours and after five incorrect fingerprint attempts

You can extend PAM to increase some items but not all will use the biometric API.

- https://github.com/Reflejo/pam-touchID

Comment: Hmmm.  My MacBook Pro goes longer than 48 hours without requiring password instead of touch.  The previous one (probably a hardware issue) would often seem to have forgotten touch ID for days at a time, and the work for a short time.